# Unable to hide handsontable column header when i use td.hidden = true; cell render

Tags: handsontable

I have used the following custom column render code for hiding handsontable column

```
function getCustomRenderer() {
return function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
  if (colsToHide.indexOf(col) > -1) {
    td.hidden = true;
  } else {
    td.hidden = false;
  }
}
```

but when i set `colHeaders: true,` the column headers does not get hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/LkLkd405/91/

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you can't hide the column headers that way since the rendering happens independently of the column renderers. I will go ahead and assume your endgoal is to put in data into your `data` object that you would like to hide, like a database ID. The solution is to use the `columns` definition.

This option, if you read the documentation carefully, allows you to define which columns to show. So, for example, if you had 3 columns plus your ID column, you would have:

```
var colHeaders = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'ID'];

// assume `dataArray` is an aray you previously defined, with row Objects with 4 keys each, corresponding to the first 3 real data columns and the fourth as the ID.
columns: [{
    data: colHeaders[0],
    type: 'text'
},{
    data: colHeaders[1],
    type: 'text'
},{
    data: colHeaders[2],
    type: 'text'
}]
```

Now you don't even need to have a custom renderer as the table will omit that fourth value.

Answer (score 0):

```
hot.addHook('afterGetColHeader', RemoveUnWantedHeader); 

function RemoveUnWantedHeader(col, th) {
    if (th.textContent == "A" || th.textContent == "B" || th.textContent == "C" 
       || th.textContent == "D" || th.textContent == "E"
       || th.textContent == "F" || th.textContent == "G" || th.textContent == "H" 
       || th.textContent == "I" || th.textContent == "J"
       || th.textContent == "K" || th.textContent == "L" || th.textContent == "M" 
       || th.textContent == "N" || th.textContent == "O"
       || th.textContent == "P" || th.textContent == "Q" || th.textContent == "R" 
       || th.textContent == "S" || th.textContent == "T"
       || th.textContent == "U" || th.textContent == "V" || th.textContent == "W" 
       || th.textContent == "X" || th.textContent == "Y" || th.textContent == "Z"
       || th.textContent == "AQ" || th.textContent == "AR" || th.textContent == "AS"
       || th.textContent == "AT" || th.textContent == "AU" || th.textContent == "AV" || th.textContent == "AW") {
        th.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

I have used hook to remove the headers I need to. I tried the same inside my HandsonTable it doesn't work so I tried the same using `addHook` and worked like charm.

`afterGetColHeader`: It is a function which will be rendered when header is called.

`RemoveUnWantedHeader`: It is my own callback. You can have your own conditions and can remove.

[Reference: Handsontable Add Hooks](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta3/Core.html#addHook)